# What type of algorithm is used for C# expressions?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, expression, postfix-notation

[Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) is used to convert expressions from infix to postfix notation (Reverse Polish notation), so that it is eaiser to evaluate them by a compiler. For example, `2 + 3 * 2` would be converted to `2 3 2 * +`. In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation#Current_implementations), it is mentioned that this algorithm is used by many applications including

> Any stack-oriented programming language, such as:
>       Forth, 
>       Factor, 
>       PostScript page description language, 
>       Befunge, 
>       Joy

I don't see C# or even any popular high-level language. So, does C# use this algorithm for expressions? If no, how does C#-compiler compile and evaluate expressions?

Comment: Your Wikipedia quote doesn't refer to the way the languages represent the program internally, it's just talking about the languages that use Reverse Polish as the way that programmers write the programs. Your question isn't really meaningful.

Comment: @Barmar Ok, I'm asking wether C# uses this algorithm too

Comment: That's not a meaningful question, either. Every compiler works differently. Why does it matter, what problem are you trying to solve that depends on the internal design of the C# compiler?

Comment: I just would know what is the algorithm used (being curious) to convert `(a + b) * c` into Common-Intermediate-Language. So how does it know that (a + b) must be calculated first? Does the compiler uses Shunting-Yard algorithm? or represent the expression as a tree?

Comment: Best person to answer - Eric Lippert.

Comment: There are at least 4 C# compilers, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#C.23_compilers

Comment: @Barmar Is it necessary that all questions on SO focus on the specifics of a construction problem? While perhaps slightly broad in it's remit, there's a lot to be learned from this question.

Comment: From the FAQ: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."

Comment: Such a boring and rigid faq. I suppose it's my duty to vote to close. Sorry @Desolator! Why not take this over to programmers.stackexchange instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, C# is converted to a stack-oriented programming language -- [IL](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nrsurapaneni/ILtheLangOfCLRbyNRS12222005040956AM/ILtheLangOfCLRbyNRS.aspx). When the compiler converts an expression to the internal language, it makes a list of operations that follow RPN.

For example, this method

```
int x(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    return a+b*(c+d);
}
```

gets converted to this internal language (see comments for explanation of what is going on):

```
IL_0001:  ldarg.0 // Push a on the stack
IL_0002:  ldarg.1 // Push b on the stack
IL_0003:  ldarg.2 // Push c on the stack
IL_0004:  ldarg.3 // Push d on the stack
IL_0005:  add     // Add d+c, push the result
IL_0006:  mul     // Multiply (d+c) by b
IL_0007:  add     // Add b*(d+c)+a
```

As you can see, the operands are pushed onto stack in the order that makes it convenient to perform operations by working from the back of the expression to its front - exactly the way the article explains it.

The exact algorithm of the conversion is compiler-dependent (strictly speaking, the end result is compiler-dependent as well, because there are multiple ways to convert an expression to a valid RPN sequence) but the basic idea of RPN is there.

Comment: Suddenly a problem I've been working on that is only distantly related to what I see here has popped into 3d. An unrelated +1!